# Ayuda con parámetro de entrada en batch input ABAP

Tags: abap

Estoy creando un batch input en ABAP y al momento de ejecutarlo desde mi programa, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Field BKPF-BLART  longitud de valor entrada mayor que el campo dynpro.
```

Intenté arreglarlo usando la sentencia `CONDENSE` y cambiando el tipo de parámetro a `CHAR2`.

¿Alguna otra idea?

```
PARAMETERS:
    p_bldat  TYPE CHAR10,   "Fecha de documento.
    p_budat  TYPE CHAR10,   "Fecha de contabilización.
    p_xblnr  TYPE XBLNR,    "Referencia.
    p_bktxt  TYPE BKTXT,    "Texto cabecera.
    p_blart  TYPE BLART,    "Clase.
    ...........

    PERFORM OPEN_GROUP.
     PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0100'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLDAT'  'p_bldat'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUDAT'  'p_budat'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-XBLNR'  'p_xblnr'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BKTXT'  'p_bktxt'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLART'  'p_blart'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-MONAT'  'p_monat'.
     ......
```

Gracias!

Comment: Sería bueno que muestres ese batch input del cual hablas ya que "al momento de ejecutarlo" no sabemos de qué estas hablando exactamente

Comment: @CésarBustíos Listo, checa mi actualización.

Comment: También ayudaría conocer los datos de entrada...

Comment: 7.7 Ahí estan declarados....

Comment: De todas formas, si puedes encontrar cualquier otra forma de añadir información a tu sistema que no sea a través de un Batch-Input, tu empleador te lo agradecerá a medio o largo plazo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás pasando los valores de esas variables si no cadenas:

```
'p_blart' -> es una cadena porque está entre comillas simples
```

En su lugar, para pasar los valores sería:

```
PERFORM OPEN_GROUP.
 PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0100'.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLDAT'  p_bldat.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUDAT'  p_budat.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-XBLNR'  p_xblnr.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BKTXT'  p_bktxt.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLART'  p_blart.
  PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-MONAT'  p_monat.
```

Comment: Muy bien, esta era la solucion, gracias!